# cannot export function in Express

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js, mean-stack, passport-local

I'm trying to implement passport.js and problem is in the way of exporting function in model:

User model file (user.js) looks like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

userSchema.methods = {

    getUserByUsername: function(username, callback){
        var query = {username: username};
        userSchema.findOne(query, callback);
        /*userSchema.findOne(query, function(err, user) {
            callback(err, user);
        }); */
    },

    getUserById: function(id, callback){
        userSchema.findById(id, callback);
    },

    comparePassword: function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
        bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
            if(err) throw err;
            callback(null, isMatch);
        });
    }
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I call the model (app.js):

```
// user schema/model
var User = require('./models/user.js');
```

and I'm trying to use exported functions in passport (app.js):

```
passport.use(new localStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(isMatch){
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
      }
    });
   });
  }));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

I got `TypeError: User.getUserByUsername is not a function`

I tried to define a function regarding [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html):

```
User.methods.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
        var query = {username: username};
        User.findOne(query, callback);
    }
```

and the same error apperas in the console when I'm trying to login..

EDIT:
I've added:

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = {
  User: User
};
```

and now it works with methods definition:

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername()
```

so the final model file looks like:

```
// user model
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = {
  User: User
};

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
    var query = {username: username};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
        if(err) throw err;
        callback(null, isMatch);
    });
}
```

Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: And how do you require it? `User` is defined in the User model, but unless you did something like `var User = require...` it won't be in passport ?

Comment: I referenced model with `var User = require('./models/user.js');` in `app.js` so passport may have access to the model, right?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = ...
```

or

```
User.methods.getUserByUsername = ...
```

use

```
User.statics.getUserByUsername = ...
```

See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html

Comment: I tried with `User.statics.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
 var query = {username: username};
 User.findOne(query, callback);
}` and the same error appears :(

Comment: @corry Where did you put that code? `User` must refer to the schema, not the User after being exported.

Comment: Of course, schema is defined as `var User = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
});` and the `User.statics.getUserByUsername` is defined in the same file (user.js) instead of `module.exports.getUserByUsername` as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to NodeJS then understanding **module.exports** and **exports** can be a bit confusing. It's important to be crystal clear with this concept because you will frequently encounter this if yet get into serious nodejs development.
I am not going to explain how the exports work in nodejs here because there are plenty of tutorials in web. eg; Please read [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/).

Follow my code below to fix your issue.

```
//UserModel.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var userSchema = mongoose.schema({
      username: String,
      password: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

userSchema.methods = {
    createUser: function(...){..},
    getUserByUsername: function(..){..},
    getUserById: function(..){..},
    comparePassword: function(..),{}

}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

You can access the methods from your UserSchema as:

```
//Controller.js
var User  = require('path/to/UserModel.js');
User.createUser(..,..)
```

For more details you can refer to my repository and see how i am doing it [here](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/nghtml5jwt/blob/master/app/authorization/models/UserModel.js).

Comment: Thank you for the your explanation, it's much clerar now, but still the sam error appears. I've defined the userSchema methods in object as in your example `userSchema.methods = {
 getUserByUsername: function(username, callback){
  var query = {username: username};
  userSchema.findOne(query, callback);
 },
 getUserById: function(id, callback){
  userSchema.findById(id, callback);
 },...
}`and called it in the app.js `User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
    }`

Comment: Could you please update the question with you current code.. Model, How you are calling etc.. I will be able to help then..